# PHP dividing not working

Tags: php, html

This is a *send.php* file, I want it to take `$givenRating` which was submitted through a form, divide it by the amount of people who have rated that person (`$numberOfRatings`), then send that data off to a text file after rounding it. However, all that happens is the number entered in the form box gets added to their rating.

```
$givenRating     = $_POST['rating']; /* Works */
$teacher1        = $_GET['teacher1'];/* Works */
$teacherRating   = file_get_contents("../game/teacher-profiles/" 
                                      . $teacher1 . "/rating.txt"); /* Works */
$numberOfRatings = file_get_contents("../game/teacher-profiles/" 
                                      . $teacher1 . "/ratings.txt"); /* Works */
settype($teacherRating,   "integer"); 
settype($numberOfRatings, "integer");
settype($givenRating,     "integer");

$finalRating     = $givenRating / $numberOfRatings;

if($finalRating > $teacherRating) {
    $send_rating = $teacherRating + $finalRating;
}
if($finalRating < $teacherRating) {
    $send_rating = $teacherRating - $finalRating;
}

$send_rating     = round($send_rating); 
$file            = fopen("../game/teacher-profiles/" 
                          . $teacher1 . "/rating.txt", "w") 
                          or die("Unable to open file!");

fwrite($file, $send_rating);
```

Comment: seems so similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/41314429/1415724 wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the String `(Path)` passed to the `file_get_contents()` Method for both: `$teacherRating` and `$numberOfRatings`in your Code. They seem to be exactly the same. Secondly, you may need to explicitly cast some values from String to either Integer or Float Values before using them in any Arithmetic Operation(s). See the Snippet below ---

```
<?php
    $givenRating     = isset($_POST['rating'])  ? intval(trim($_POST['rating']))  : 0;
    $teacher1        = isset($_GET['teacher1']) ? trim($_GET['teacher1'])         : '';
    $tRatingFile     = "../game/teacher-profiles/". $teacher1 . "/rating.txt";
    $numRatingFile   = "../game/teacher-profiles/". $teacher1 . "/ratings.txt";

    // NOTICE/WARNING: THE $tRatingFile & THE $numRatingFile ARE THE SAME
    // IS THIS CORRECT? COMPARE WITH YOUR ORIGINAL POST...
    $teacherRating   = ($data = file_get_contents($tRatingFile))   ? floatval($data) : 0;
    $numberOfRatings = ($data = file_get_contents($numRatingFile)) ? floatval($data) : 0;
    $send_rating     = 0;    //<== INITIALIZE $send_rating TO ZERO: 0

    /*********************************************/
    /*** UNNECESSARY BLOCK: SEE intval() ABOVE ***/
    /*********************************************/
    /*--------------------------------------------
    | settype($teacherRating,   "integer");      |
    | settype($numberOfRatings, "integer");      |
    | settype($givenRating,     "integer");      |
    ---------------------------------------------*/

    $finalRating     = $givenRating/$numberOfRatings;

    if($finalRating > $teacherRating) {
        $send_rating = $teacherRating + $finalRating;
    }
    if($finalRating < $teacherRating) {
        $send_rating = $teacherRating - $finalRating;
    }

    $send_rating     = round($send_rating);
    $file            = fopen($tRatingFile, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

    fwrite($file, $send_rating);
```

Comment: That seems to write "2" to every file? Also thanks for the warning, but those files are actually different. `rating.txt` is the rating, `ratings.txt` is the amount of people who rated that teacher